# Build has_one relationship

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have schemas, that looks as follow:

```
defmodule Busiket.LanguageCode do

  use Busiket.Web, :model


  schema "languages_code" do

        field :code, :string
        field :text, :string

        timestamps
  end
end
```

the second schema:

```
defmodule Busiket.CountryCode do

  use Busiket.Web, :model

  schema "countries_code" do

    field :alpha2, :string
    field :alpha3, :string

    timestamps
  end

end
```

and the third table

```
defmodule Busiket.Country do

  use Busiket.Web, :model

  alias Busiket.LanguageCode
  alias Busiket.CountryCode

  schema "countries" do

    has_one :code, CountryCode
    has_one :lang, LanguageCode
    field :text, :string

    timestamps

  end

end
```

as you can see on the third schema, the field `code` should depends on `country_code` schema with field `code`.

The lang field should depends on `language_code` schema with field `alpha2`.

I do not know, if the schema country is well designed?

The entries in the countries should looks like:

```
"CH" | "EN" | "Switzerland"
"DE" | "EN" | "Germany"
```

and this record should faild:

```
"YY" | "EN" | "Foo"
```

because there is no a country with `YY` iso code.

The migration file from `language_code` looks as follow:

```
defmodule Busiket.Repo.Migrations.CreateLanguageCode do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do

     create table(:languages_code) do

      add :code, :string, size: 3
      add :text, :string

      timestamps

    end

  end
end
```

and `country_code`

```
defmodule Busiket.Repo.Migrations.CreateCountryCode do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do

      create table(:countries_code) do

      add :alpha2, :string, size: 2
      add :alpha3, :string, size: 3

      timestamps
    end

  end
end
```

and at last I tried with `country` migration:

```
defmodule Busiket.Repo.Migrations.CreateCountryTable do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do

    create table(:countries) do

    add :code, references(:countries_code), [name: :alpha2]
    add :lang, references(:languages_code), [name: :code]
    add :text, :string

    timestamps

    create unique_index(:countries, [:code, :lang])

    end
  end
end
```

I hope, it is clear what I want to reach.

**UPDATE**

I created the table as you sad:

```
defmodule Busiket.Repo.Migrations.CreateCountryTable do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do

        create table(:countries) do

          add :coun, references(:countries_code, column: :alpha2, type: :string)
      add :lang, references(:languages_code, column: :code, type: :string)
          add :text, :string

          timestamps
        end

        create unique_index(:countries, [:coun, :lang])

  end
end
```

When I execute mix ecto.migrate, I've got following error:

```
20:34:11.012 [info]  create table countries
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (invalid_foreign_key): there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "countries_code"
```

I think, I have to change :alpha3 not to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You want `belongs_to` in `Country` since `Country`'s table contains the foreign keys. You also need to specify the foreign table's column name in `belongs_to`.

   ```
   schema "countries" do
     belongs_to :code, CountryCode, foreign_key: :alpha2
     belongs_to :lang, LanguageCode, foreign_key: :code
     ...
   end
   ```

   The `has_one` declarations should be in `CountryCode` and `LanguageCode` schemas.
2. The option you want to specify in the migration is `column`, and that should be in the call to `references`. (There is no `name` option in `add`, which your current code is using.) You also need to specify `type`.

   ```
   create table(:countries) do
     add :code, references(:countries_code, column: :alpha2, type: :string)
     add :lang, references(:languages_code, column: :code, type: :string)
     ...
   end
   ```

Comment: How does has_one in `CountryCode` and `LanguageCode` schemas should looks like?

Comment: I think you need to also add a unique index for `alpha2` in `countries_code` and `code` in `languages_code`. Make sure to re-run the migrations if you edit existing migration to add those fields.